# SQL Login System

Tags: php, sql, authentication, mysqli

I coded this login system, but whenever I try to log in with the only username and password included in my database table, I get redirected to index.php?error=sqlerror. I checked the code for spelling mistakes but there are none. Could this be a problem with the database connection? I use MAMP. I have checked the database and it displays the Success message so it seems to be working. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

DATABASE CONNECTION (file name: dbh.inc.php)

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "gallerydatabase";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.";
}
echo "Success";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

LOG-IN PHP CODE (file name: login.inc.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

  require 'dbh.inc.php';

  $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];

  if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
    header ("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();
  }
  else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header ("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }
    else {

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mailuid);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
        if ($pwdCheck == false)  {
          header ("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
          exit();
        }
        else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
          $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

          header ("Location: ../index.php?login=sucess");
          exit();

        }
        else {
          header ("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
          exit();
        }
      }
      else {
        header ("Location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
        exit();
      }

    }
  }
}
else {
  header ("Location: ../index.php");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php instead of the redirect and it will tell you.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have checked the database and it displays the Success message ". If you mean your echo "Success"; from dbh.inc.php is printing then unless an exception occurs during connection, it is always going to printed since you have not put that in else section.

Comment: I mean my echo "Sucess" is printing, as you say. Do you think my database connection is not working? Thank you!

Comment: @Blue - I hope you are consulting the answer I have provided, where I have also explained the reason

Comment: You were right! The problem was that I was closing my db connection. Thank you! However, now I when I write the correct username and password to log in, I get redirected to index.php?error=wrongpwd. Do you know why this is happening? Again, thank you, sorry for my lack of skills.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your file dbh.inc.php, you create the connection **$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);** and later you close it as well **mysqli_close($conn);**.

So by the time you come to use $conn in login.inc.php your connection is closed. What you need to do is write a function in dbh.inc.php that returns a live connection (don't call close), use that to do your DB queries / insert and after that close the connection.

A reusable database class can be written (functional style) as follows

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

trait DBInfo {
  protected $servername = "127.0.0.1";
    protected $username = "root";
    protected $password = "";
    protected $dbname = "gallerydatabase";
}

class Database{
  use DBInfo;
  function __construct() {}

  function connection(){
      $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, 
$this->password, $this->dbname);
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } else{
        $conn->autocommit(FALSE);
        return $conn;
      }
  }

  function select($sql, $fn2bind_takestmt, $fn2process_row_return_result){
    try{
      $result = array();
      $conn = $this->connection();
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $fn2bind_takestmt($stmt);
      $stmt->execute();
      $rowset = $stmt->get_result();
      while ($row = $rowset->fetch_assoc()) {
        $obj = $fn2process_row_return_result($row);
        array_push($result, $obj);
      }
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        $result = NULL;
        throw $e;
    }finally{
      if(isset($rowset))$rowset->close();
      if(isset($stmt))$stmt->close();
      if(isset($conn))$conn->close();
    }
    return $result;
  }

  // You can introduce functions for insert, update and delete as well

}

?>
```

and then for database selects for example login check

```
<?php
function allow_login($user, $pwd){
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) rec_count FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? and pwdUsers=?"
    $db = new Database();
    $result = $db->select($sql,
                function($stmt) use($user, $pwd){
                  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pwd); 
                },
                function($row){
                  if($row['rec_count'] > 0){// or whatever
                    return TRUE;
                  }
                    return FALSE;
                }
             );
    if(isset($result)){
      return $result[0];
    }
    return $result;
  }  
?>
```